# Github action binaries execution colors

Tags: colors, github-actions

When using github action and `shell: bash` parameter, I don't get the color output from the command I am executing.

Example:

- Using binary `kube-score`

Here is my script in github action:

```yaml
name: 'Kube-score'
description: 'Kubernetes object analysis with recommendations for improved reliability and security.'
author: 'ixxeL'
inputs:
  format:
    description: 'Format result. [human,ci,json]'
    required: false
    default: 'human'
  kube-version:
    description: 'Setting the kubernetes-version will affect the checks ran against the manifests.'
    required: false
    default: 'v1.18'
  working-dir:
    description: 'file to scan'
    required: false
    default: './*.yaml'
runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
    - id: kube-score
      shell: bash
      run: |
        kube-score score --output-format=${{ inputs.format }} \
                         --kubernetes-version=${{ inputs.kube-version }} \
                         ${{ inputs.working-dir }}
```

And the result when code is executed :

[Output result in github action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElpRK.png)

when it should look like this (on my terminal):

[Output result in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vchaC.png)

Any idea on how to force colors in my output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [actions/runner issue 241](https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/241), this could be a TTY problem: no TTY detected, no color generated by the [`zegl/kube-score`](https://github.com/zegl/kube-score) command.

Try and force one (a TTY) with:

```
shell: 'script --return --quiet --command "bash {0}"'
run: |
 <command requiring TTY>
```

Comment: Thanks it's working like a charm indeed !
Since I am running my github actions in containers (alpine), I had to add the package `util-linux` to be able to call `script` as in your example, but at the end, it's working fine

Comment: @ixxeL Great, well done!